# How does one convert a simple program to a HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have the following program:

```
    public class PopularCharacter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PopularCharacter popularCharacter = new PopularCharacter();
        char result = popularCharacter.charCounter("azzo");
        System.out.println("PopularChar " + result);
    }
    public char charCounter(String input) {
        int maxIndex = 0;
        int maxValue = 0;
        int[] value = new int[26];

        for (int index = 0; index < input.length(); index++) {
            value[input.charAt(index) - 97]++;
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < value.length; index++) {
            if (value[index] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = value[index];
                maxIndex = index;
            }
        }

        return (char) (maxIndex + 97);
    }
}
```

how should I modify the code to implement with HashMap?
It's my first time that I am going to use the HashMap and I am very confused. I ask you the base to restructure the code.

I tried to do that, but I know is worthless:

```
    import java.util.*;

public class MaxCharHM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MaxCharHM popularchar = new MaxCharHM();
        char result = popularchar.charCounter("aabbaacdcldkaalkccccc");
        System.out.println("Popular char: " + result);
    }

    public HashMap <Character, Integer> buildMap (String input){

            HashMap value = new HashMap();
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                value.put[input.charAt(i) - 97]++;

        return (char) (something + 97)

   etc etc
            }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first understand what a map is and what / how does it store data.. once you are there, you will get answer to your problem.. just look at argument list for Map.put(key k, value v)

Comment: @hlmAnShU: Should I mess up the entire code, or the solution is close the first program?

Comment: in the code sample above, you used a list with index value as 26.. and the value at that index was the number of occurrence of a character.. Map will map the data from key to index.. so you will have 26 keys in your map and every time you find the character in the 'input', you increment the value by 1.. it's very similar to the logic of list in that way..

Comment: My intervention was due to the fact to determine whether the transformation was to take place only in the method HashMap or even in the main.
I wondered the guidelines, not the exercise solution.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'll try to do my best following your suggest.

Comment: why should main be bothered what's happening inside the method..? as long as the method signature is same.. it's only the data structure you are changing..